# DataBinding onClickListener giving error using "::"

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm following the google databinding tutorial and it shows that they bind using

```
public class MyHandlers {
    public void onClickFriend(View view) { ... }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="handlers" type="com.example.MyHandlers"/>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"
           android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

How come when I do the samething and use the `android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"/>` it gives me the error

```
Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method eventHandlers::onAddPhotosClick
```

My class:

```
public class EventHandlers {
    public void onAddPhotosClick(){
        //dosomething
    }

}
```

XML for view:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/fragevent_tv_addphotosbutton2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
 android:onClick="@{eventHandlers::onAddPhotosClick}"/>
```

Comment: You're missing the `View` parameter. That's what it means by "did not match signature".

Comment: oh I see. Didnt think I needed it because it was greyed out and said Parameter view is never used. Thanks that fixed the problem